# Encrypting in C# and Decrypting with Crypto++ does not work

Tags: c#, sockets, encryption, crypto++

Encryption :

```
    public static byte[] EncryptAES(Message msg)
    {

        byte[] encText; // This will keep the encrypted text
        byte[] encLength; // This will keep the length of the encrypted text
        byte[] finalEncText = null; // This keeps the encLength + encText (#####[encText] / [encLength][encText])

        // Building the plaintext message : 
        string plainText = msg.MessageCode.ToString();

        if (msg.Parameters != null)
            foreach (string parameter in msg.Parameters)
                plainText += parameter;

        // Encrypting the plaintext :
        encText = EncryptAES(plainText);

        string encLen = encText.Length.ToString();
        string fittedEncLen = MessageSender.FitStringIntoSize(encLen, Globals.MESSAGE_LENGTH_LEN); // Fit the length of the encrypted text into a certain size
        encLength = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fittedEncLen); // convert the length into byte[]

        finalEncText = new byte[encLength.Length + encText.Length];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(encLength, 0, finalEncText, 0, encLength.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(encText, 0, finalEncText, encLength.Length, encText.Length); // Copy the byte arrays into the new byte array


        return finalEncText;
    }

    private static byte[] EncryptAES(string text)
    {
        // This function encrypts a plaintext message using the aes key we have from the server

        if (AesKey == null || IV == null) // If we dont have an aes key / iv, dont encrypt
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);


        byte[] encryptedText;

        try
        {
            Aes aes = Aes.Create();
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            aes.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AesKey);
            aes.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);

            ICryptoTransform cryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);



            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream crypotStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, cryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writerStream = new StreamWriter(crypotStream))
                    {
                        writerStream.Write(text);
                    }
                    encryptedText = memStream.ToArray();
                }
            }

            aes.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
            // In case of an error while encrypting, dont encrypt
            encryptedText = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        }
        return encryptedText;
    }
```

**[The added fittedEncLen is basically a prefix of fixed length of 5 chars, that contains the length of the encrypted message following it, before decrypting the server reads those 5 chars and then it decrypts the encrypted part]**

Sending the message to the server [TCPClient] [C#] :

```
public int Send(Message message)
        {
            /*
             * Encrpyts the message and then sends it to the network stream.
             * 
             * Return code:
             *      0 on success.
             *      -1 on failure.
             */

            byte[] msg = Cryptography.EncryptAES(message); // Encrypt the message
            // Sending message

            try
            {
                this._networkStream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                this._networkStream.Flush();
            }
            catch
            {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Receiving [C++] :

```
wstring Helper::getWideStringPartFromSocket(SOCKET sc, int bytesNum)
{
    // This function reads the message from the socket, using wide string
    std::wstringstream cls;
    cls << getPartFromSocket(sc, bytesNum, 0);
    return cls.str();
}

char* Helper::getPartFromSocket(SOCKET sc, int bytesNum, int flags)
{
    if (bytesNum == 0)
        return "";

    char* data = new char[bytesNum + 1];
    int res = recv(sc, data, bytesNum, flags);

    if (res == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        string s = "Error while recieving from socket: ";
        s += to_string(sc);
        throw exception(s.c_str());
    }

    data[bytesNum] = 0;

    return data;
}



BufferedString* Helper::makeBufferedString(SOCKET sc)
    {
        /*
            The socket contains <length of encrypted message (unencrypted)> <encrypted message>.

            This function will read the length of the unencrypted message, read 
            the encrypted message, decrypt it, store it in a BufferedString
            object and return the object.

            Length of length number: MESSAGE_LENGTH_LEN.
        */

        int sizeOfMessage = Helper::getIntPartFromSocket(sc, MESSAGE_LENGTH_LEN);
        if (sizeOfMessage == 0)
            return NULL;

        wstring wideString = getWideStringPartFromSocket(sc, sizeOfMessage);
        string decrypted = "";

        if (wideString.length() < sizeOfMessage)
        {
            std::wstringstream cls;
            cls << wideString;
            cls << getWideStringPartFromSocket(sc, sizeOfMessage - wideString.length());
            wideString = cls.str();
        }

        SocketEncryptionKeychain* keyChain = SocketEncryptionKeychain::getKeychain(sc);

        if (keyChain != nullptr) // If the socket has a keychain, decrypt the message
            decrypted = Cryptography::decryptAES(wideString, keyChain->getKey(), keyChain->getIV()); // Try to decrypt the message
        else // If the keychain is null, just convert the widestring to a string
            decrypted = wideStringToString(wideString);

        return new BufferedString(decrypted);
    }
```

**SocketEncryptionKeychain basically contains the AES Key and IV for each socket
BufferedString is a class that contains the string, and you can read from it like you read from a socket [its a buffer that once you read from it, what you read is deleted] [basically a string buffer, nothing special]**

Decrypting [C++]:

```
string Cryptography::decryptAES(wstring cipherText, byte aesKey[], byte iv[])
{
    if (aesKey == nullptr || iv == nullptr) // If the key or iv are null, dont decrypt
        return Helper::wideStringToString(cipherText);

    string plaintext;
    try
    {
        // Decrypt :
        byte* cipher = wideStringToByteArray(cipherText); // Convert the wide string to byte*

        CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(aesKey, 32);
        CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption ecbDecryption(aesDecryption, iv);


        CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(ecbDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(plaintext), StreamTransformationFilter::ZEROS_PADDING);
        stfDecryptor.Put(cipher, cipherText.length());
        stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();

        Helper::safeDelete(cipher);
    }
    catch (CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext& ex)
    {
        // In case of an error don't decrypt
        plaintext = Helper::wideStringToString(cipherText);
    }

    return plaintext;
}


byte* Cryptography::wideStringToByteArray(wstring text)
{
    // This function translates the wstring into a byte*
    byte* bytes = new byte[text.length()]; // Convert the wstring to byte*
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = text[i];
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

**[Helper::safeDelete is a function that just deletes the pointer and sets it as null]**

**The decryption only fails once in a while**

Comment: first - did you verify that what you send is what you received. Ie have you got a bug in your tcp code

Comment: cos you dont seem to have a way of ensuring that you received the whole message. TCP is a streaming protocl, not a block protocol.

Comment: @pm100 I am trying to currently verify that, it seems that it is, but the bug occurs at random, only once in every X messages. hard to recreate

Comment: You are using TCP as transport layer which can break datagrams into smaller packets and combine packets. Yoor receive method is making a bad assumption that you will always getting an encrypted packet in one receive message and not splitting or combining packet.  Add test to receiver to make sure you are always getting correct number of receive bytes.  Recommend adding byte count to beginning of each message and then checking byte count when receiving data.

Comment: @jdweng I already add the byte count to the beginning of each message, at the C# Encryption part [find the variable fittedEncLen], and when reading I read the byte count and then reading byteCount bytes from the socket

Comment: Are your occasional errors associated with an incorrect byte count?

Comment: @jdweng I am trying to recreate it, I remember once seeing it did have incorrect byte count, although I directly read from the socket 17 bytes, but it only retrieved 15, which is weird.

Comment: @jdweng While debugging more I discovered something. The server is prepared to read more bytes than it gets, so if the message is 17 bytes long, the server will only get lets say 15, and it wont get the rest [ I tried looping until recv read all of the requested bytes ], and it only happens when I use encryption

Comment: @jdweng I think I have solved it! not sure yet, ill close the thread after I debug for another day to make sure its 100% fixed.
So what seems to be the problem is the process of parsing char* to wstring.
I used wstringstream, now the encrypted text is full of null chars, and apparently the wstringstream.str() function will stop reading after a null char, and I completely looked over it. so after putting a log everywhere I figured out the problem is there, because I received 32 bytes, but only parsed 16? further investigation lead me to find out that it is wstringstream causing it [cont...]

Comment: @jdweng [cont...] So what I did instead is replace the wstringstream in Helper::getWideStringPartFromSocket to : 
char* readBuffer = getPartFromSocket(sc, bytesNum, 0);
return wstring(&readBuffer[0], &readBuffer[bytesNum]);

Comment: This is a problem: `char* Helper::getPartFromSocket`. You can't use a `char*` because there will be embedded NULL's in the cipher text. Your API needs to account for both a pointer and a length. Also see [Having trouble decrypting a well-formed cipher text using Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34167305/608639).

Comment: Also, how do you tell when the message is done? Maybe you should switch to Google's [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), [Binary JSON](http://bsonspec.org/), etc to handle message framing. It will ensure you respect the message boundary.

Comment: Finally, this is going to be a problem: `aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;`. Crypto++ uses PKCS #5 padding by default. In fact, you should switch to an [Authenticated Encryption mode](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) to detect tampering.

Comment: I voted to close this as ***Too Broad***. You have too many problems in too many places. You should remove the network code, and get interop working between C# and Crypto++ with a file or hard coded values. Later, post a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a specific problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once..."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was while parsing the char* to wstring in the function

The problem in this function is the way I parse it:

```
wstring Helper::getWideStringPartFromSocket(SOCKET sc, int bytesNum)
{
    // This function reads the message from the socket, using wide string
    std::wstringstream cls;
    cls << getPartFromSocket(sc, bytesNum, 0);
    return cls.str();
}
```

I used a wstringstream, and the encrypted text can sometimes contain null-terminating character.

So instead of using a wstringstream I used this:

```
wstring Helper::getWideStringPartFromSocket(SOCKET sc, int bytesNum)
{
    // This function reads the message from the socket, using wide string
    char* readBuffer = getPartFromSocket(sc, bytesNum, 0);

    return wstring(&readBuffer[0], &readBuffer[bytesNum]);
}
```

and then it does not cut the message at null-character

Answer (score 1):

You may have other problems, but here's one:

```
using (CryptoStream crypotStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, cryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
    using (StreamWriter writerStream = new StreamWriter(crypotStream))
    {
        writerStream.Write(text);
    }
    encryptedText = memStream.ToArray();
}
```

You drained the CryptoStream's output before telling the CryptoStream it was done.  So you've possibly lost up to 16 bytes.

You need to either:

- call FlushFinalBlock() on `crypotStream`(sic).
- don't call `memStream.ToArray()` until after the using for the CryptoStream has exited.